# handlebars each in each arguments

Tags: object, handlebars.js, each

Hi I have this problem with HB.
This are my example arguments saved in a variables

```
var data = {
      people: [ Katz", Johnson", Jolley"],
      color:['blue','red','green'],
      myClass:['first',second,'third']
    }

<div class="people_list">
   {{#each data}}
    <div>{{people}}
        {{#each color}}
        <div class='{{ProblemHereMyClass}}'>{{this}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

How to print key myClass. I try more & more time, follow several tips but no result.
Have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `../` to change the scope while looping. Second use `lookup` to pick an array item by `@index`.

```
<div class="people_list">
  {{#each data.people}}
    <div>{{this}}
      {{#each ../data.color}}
        <div class="{{lookup ../../data.myClass @index}}">{{this}}</div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: It's ben hard, and bit different. But really thank for your helpful!!! THX!